# Why is this value 3 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, post-increment

I think the code below should display 4, why does it produce 3?

```js
function arithFunc() {
    var n = 0;
    return {
        plusOP: function() {
            return n++;
        },
        minusOP: function() {
            return n--;
        }

    };
}

var aTest = arithFunc(),
    bTest = arithFunc();

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = aTest.plusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = aTest.plusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = bTest.minusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = aTest.plusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = bTest.minusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = aTest.plusOP();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: First thing to do is correct your code formatting so that we can understand easily.

Comment: It might help a lot to fill an array with all the result values and look at all of them, not only the last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using postfix increment and decrement operators. These are calculated after the value is returned. For example:

```
var n = 0;
console.log(n++); // 0
console.log(n); // 1
```

Try using prefix operators instead:

```
var n = 0;
console.log(++n); // 1
console.log(n); // 1
```

Your code would then look like:

```
function arithFunc() {
    var n = 0;
    return {
        plusOP: function() {
            return ++n;
        },
        minusOP: function() {
            return --n;
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: I suggest showing `console.log(++n);` behavior as well

Comment: @PatrickBarr Good point, added.

Comment: I understand. Thank you~

Comment: @Jehyun Can you mark this answer as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

You are over-complicating things: `n++` evaluates to the value of `n`, and then increments `n`.

`aTest` and `bTest` have their own private copies of `n`, so all those `bTest.minusOP` invocations are irrelevant to the final contents of `p#demo` which only gets the value returned by the last `plusOP`.

`n` starts out as zero. The first `return n++` returns `0` and increments `n` to `1`. The next `return n++` returns `1` and increments it to `2` etc etc

```js
function arithFunc() {
  var n = 0;
  return {
    plusOP: function() {
      return n++;
    },
    minusOP: function() {
      return n--;
    }

  };
}

var aTest = arithFunc(),
  bTest = arithFunc();

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " " + aTest.plusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " " + aTest.plusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " " + bTest.minusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " " + aTest.plusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " " + bTest.minusOP();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " " + aTest.plusOP();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```